# Custom message with validates presence of not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My `User` model contains the following:

```
validates :password_digest, :presence => true, :message => "The password has to be 6 or     more characters long"  

def password=(password)
  self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password) if password.length >= 6
end
```

The issue is that the `message` in the `validates` isn't working. I get a `Unknown validator: 'MessageValidator'` error. I assumed the way the `presence` validation worked was that it would just check if the `password_digest` was `nil`, which it would be had the `password` had a length less than 6. I want a solution that is elegant, like what I attempted. I have solved this one way, but I would really appreciate an understanding as to why what I'm trying isn't working, and is there a way to make it work.

What I got to work was:

```
validate do |user|
  user.errors['password'] = "can't be less than 6 characters" if user.password_digest.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to how the `validates` method works. It assumes that you're looking for the `MessageValidator` when you specify `:message` as a key in the hash passed to `validates`.

This can be solved by reconstructing the query as follows:

```
validates :password_digest, :presence => { :message => "The password has to be 6 or more characters long" }
```

Comment: No. It's confusing, I know, but that's how it's expected.