# Custom message for acceptance with no database column not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As per the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance) I tried:

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true, message: 'Please accept that the application is complete.'
```

But it caused MessageValidator error. Then I tried [this from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262704/custom-message-with-validates-presence-of-not-working) but this was meant for earlier Rails and didn't show my message. It was always showing only default message.

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { accept: '1', message: 'Please accept that the application is complete.' }
```